# Resource for Reading Git Man Pages?

Tags: git, command-line

I am interested in learning how to read the command-line syntax on Git Man pages. For instance, the following appears in the synopsis of [this](http://schacon.github.io/git/git.html) page

```
git [--version] [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path]
    [-p|--paginate|--no-pager] [--no-replace-objects]
    [--bare] [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>]
    [-c <name>=<value>]
    [--help] <command> [<args>]
```

Can someone please offer an explanation or resource as to how to read this syntax? A Google search brings up results for Windows and IBM syntax, but I can't find anything about Linux-type commands.

Comment: Try `git --help` or `man git` or `git help command` (for example `git help clone`). If that's not what you're looking for, please clarify.

Comment: I am trying to learn how to read the synopsis so I can invoke the command with the correct syntax.

Comment: Check out the official and completely free Git book: http://git-scm.com/book

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but as far as I can tell the Git book does not have an explanation with regards to reading the command line syntax.

Comment: Maybe you're right. The book might not have a dedicated section for this, but as you go through it, I think it will come to you naturally, little by little. I'm not a huge fan of the command line help of git, it's unclear and spotty at best. I rely heavily on stackoverflow whenever I need to do something "unusual".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Words in square brackets are optional
- Pipes (`|`) make the things in brackets mutually exclusive
- Angle brackets are placeholders for any kind of information
- words not preceded with a `-` or a `--` are placeholders for things like filenames, etc.

(from [man-pages(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/man-pages.7.html))

```
SYNOPSIS      briefly describes the command or function's interface.
             For commands, this shows the syntax of the command and
             its arguments (including options); boldface is used for
             as-is text and italics are used to indicate replaceable
             arguments.  Brackets ([]) surround optional arguments,
             vertical bars (|) separate choices, and ellipses (...)
             can be repeated.  For functions, it shows any required
             data declarations or #include directives, followed by
             the function declaration.
```

Comment: Okay, but consider the following command `git config [<file-option>] [type] --add name value`. Over here, `name` and `value` are presumably a placeholders for my information, but do not appear in angle brackets?

Comment: hmm that *is* ambiguous. Usually if it is preceded by a `-` or a `--` it is written verbatim.

Comment: @jesterII Git documentation is written in docbook and auto-converted into manual pages. This conversion does not use the standard macros that the `mdoc` groff macros provide for formatting options. In the case of git-config, there are many different invocations listed in the manual. In your example I would interpret it as follows; If you use the `--add` option, you _must_ provide both a name and a value.

Comment: @RolandSmith So, is the reason `name` and `value` aren't in `<>`'s because of an auto-conversion error? Usage syntax should (ideally) comply with [POSIX Utility Argument Syntax][https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_01]. This is a problem, e.g., with the docs for `git rebase`, which imply it can be run simply as `git rebase` without any options or arguments.

Comment: @A.Hendry, incidentally you can run `git rebase` with no arguments successfully, it just doesn't appear to do anything useful. (For me it prints "Current branch *branch_name* is up to date.", like gee, thanks.)

Comment: @AlexGittemeier Ya, actually I just realized after I posted this that I was wrong...You can rebase without arguments (my bad @RolandSmith). It works if the branch you're rebasing has a remote. e.g. if `topic` has remote `origin/topic`, then running `git rebase` from `topic` will rebase onto `origin/topic`. So weird this is default because I would think you'd run the risk of rewriting published history that way.

Comment: Huh, interesting. so `git rebase` is quite similar to a `git pull --rebase` without the `git fetch` step, if I am reading the relevant manpages correctly ^_^