# Errors in Git Documentation?

Tags: git, command-line, syntax

Per [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036490/resource-for-reading-git-man-pages), Git manpages are converted automatically from the Git docs (without using `mdoc` or `groff`), so some usage syntax and manpages do not adhere to [POSIX Utility Argument Syntax](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_01%5D).

For example:

```
man git-config
```

lists

```
git config [<file-option>] [type] --add name value
```

under "Synopsis" (per POSIX syntax, this should be under a heading called "Usage", and what's under the heading "Description" in the Git manpage should be under a heading called "Synopsis"), and `name` and `value` should appear in `<>`s to indicate they are placeholders.

More confusingly,

```
man git-rebase
```

lists

```
git rebase [-i | --interactive] [<options>] [--exec <cmd>]
               [--onto <newbase> | --keep-base] [<upstream> [<branch>]]
       git rebase [-i | --interactive] [<options>] [--exec <cmd>] [--onto <newbase>]
               --root [<branch>]
       git rebase (--continue | --skip | --abort | --quit | --edit-todo | --show-current-patch)
```

which per POSIX syntax would indicate `git rebase` can be run successfully without any options or arguments, which is not the case.

Since the Git docs do not include any sections on how to read commandline usage syntax, how am I to understand the usage syntax for `git rebase`? Should `<branch>` be placed outside of `[]`'s to properly indicate that it is in fact a non-optional argument to the command?

Comment: `git rebase` can be run without options or arguments, that's a common usage. Perhaps spending more time understanding the content and trying the commands would help understand them.

Comment: @jthill Can you please show me a usage where `git rebase` is run without arguments? I've never seen that before.

Comment: @jthill I see now `git rebase` can be run without arguments, though I find that automatic mode dangerous (more at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50643026/why-does-git-rebase-with-no-arguments-work-the-way-that-it-does). However, the issue still stands with the manpage for git config. If the usage syntax is inconsistent, and we are to read the command descriptions instead, then there is no need for usage syntax. In fact, it adds confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git tries hard to use accurate syntax descriptions in its manual pages, although it's possible that someone has made a mistake.  The `[]` syntax indicates optional arguments and the parentheses indicate a usage where one of the options is required.  This may or may not be how POSIX does it, but in general every Unix system has slightly different standards about how manual pages are to be formatted, so some divergence should be expected.  If you feel strongly about changing things, you could propose such a change on the Git list and then send some patches.

It is possible to use `git rebase` without options or arguments, as jthill pointed out.  It may or may not be a useful thing to do in your context.  Personally, I prefer to be much more explicit when rebasing with Git and so I don't use that syntax, but that's a personal prefernce; the command can be used that way, even if I choose not to.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, unfortunately I realized after posting this that I was wrong about rebase (sorry @jthill). I think the potential mistake with `git-config` is minor, but I would like to bring it to the attention of the appropriate person since I brought it up. Where is the Git list? (Does [https://git-scm.com/] or [https://github.com/git/git] say? (Had the docs for `rebase` been wrong, I think my question would have been a better one.)

Comment: Another question: If the upstream to a branch (say `topic`) is a remote (say `origin/topic`), would automatically rebasing onto `origin/topic` via running a bare `git rebase` on the `topic` branch constitute rewriting published history?

Comment: The mailing list is listed [on the website](https://git-scm.com/community).  And any rebase which isn't a no-op rewrites history.  So if you published the old one and publish the rebased version, then you're rewriting published history.  Sometimes that's okay, and sometimes it's not.